# Q: Laser cooled hydrogen

Tags: laser, hydrogen, cooling

Is it possible to cool down hydrogen some much (using lasers) to get a metalic form of the element? Or to try to produce it no such cooling is required?

Comment: Low temperature is helpful, but the main thing you need to produce metallic hydrogen is insanely high pressure. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallic_hydrogen#Metallization_of_hydrogen_under_pressure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laser cooling of atomic samples, which allows for temperature as low as few $nK$ is performed on *gaseous* samples. This is the condition for having a clean way to address a transition with a laser - the samples is essentially many times one single atom, which can be addressed with the many times one photon that constitute the laser. In solid state, interatomic interactions changes a lot the way you can play with atoms.

This means that cold atom experiments take place at very low densities (typically $10^{15}$ cm$^{-3}$). So there is no laser cooling of atomic hydrogen into metallic state, it is incompatible with the technique itself.

There is some laser cooling of solids as well, but it not suited as well - temperature reached are much higher, and you would need to start with a solid system all the same.